# Polymer Progressive Web App, placement of CSS theming variables

Tags: polymer

I am trying to restructure my Polymer app to use the progressive web app techniques expoused at Google IO.  I have a slight complication in that I need ensure the user is logged on before I can launch the app, so it will be structured so that index.html has a single `<my-session>` element embedded within it, and that element has the `<my-app>` element embedded within it.

The question is where to locate the CSS which defines the theming variables (such as --app-primary-color, and --app-accent-color etc).  In the examples, they are defined under the :host selector inside the `<my-app>` element.  In my case, that is too late, because I want to also theme my login form and the paper spinner I throw up whilst handing the session establishment.

It seems inappropriate (a vague term I know) to define these CSS theming variables inside `<my-session>`, so I was wondering if there is any downside in defining them inside a `<style>` tag with the :root selector inside `index.html`?

From reading the docs I don't think I need to declare `<style is="custom-style">` to define the custom variables, so no need to import `polymer.html` into `index.html`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In keeping with the [mediator pattern](https://youtu.be/ZDjiUmx51y8?t=616), I think you are best off creating a new, top-level element that represents your app. This is where your theming variables would be defined. The element that you previously called `<my-app>` should be renamed to something else. It's just a subcomponent of your app that changes depending on whether the user is logged in or not. You'd probably be fine defining it in `index.html`, but as time goes by you'll probably be happy that you have access to all of the full Polymer features.

`<my-app> // define your styles in this new top-level element
    <my-session> // styles defined in <my-app> cascade down to here 
    <my-dashboard> // previously called <my-app>, just an example name...`

Comment: Thanks, that is a different perspective that makes a lot of sense.